# jQuery image change on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Trying to use a fade effect by changing opacity on element hover.

The image does change according to the developer tools and the opacity also works fine on all browsers, except google chrome.

Here is my code:

```
 var default_image = $("#all_content #banner #banner_image").attr("src");


   $('#side_menu #side_menu_content li a').hover(function(){
       var image = $(this).attr("rel");
       $("#all_content #banner #banner_image").stop().animate({opacity:'0'}, function(){
            $("#all_content #banner #banner_image").attr("src", "images/"+image);               
       }).load(function(){               
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:'1'});
       });

   },
       function(){
       $("#all_content #banner #banner_image").stop().animate({opacity:'0.6'}, function(){
            $("#all_content #banner #banner_image").attr("src", default_image);               
       }).load(function(){               
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:'1'});

       });
       }
   );
```

I've noticed on chrome sometimes the image changes but inherits the opacity of 0.6 on hover out as asked for in the code, but doesn't progress to 1 afterwards. Also, sometimes after element hover, the image doesn't even load.

But works 100% on all other browsers, even IE8.

Is the .load() function buggy with Chrome? If it is, is there something I can use to substitute it?

Comment: Why not using css for opacity change on hover? css3 has some great capabilities when it comes to things like that :)

Comment: good suggestion, but I have to use images that may change on user input.

Comment: But if the images are in the same container, when you target images in that container, the hover should apply to them no matter what image you place in it.

Comment: this is very confusing code. Some hints -> the loadEvent must be there before you change the src of an element. If an image is already in the cache, a load event isn't always fired